# QML QQuickImageProvider creation and registration

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I need to create my own `QImageProvider` object in order to use QImage from RAM in QML. I've created it but it uses path that needs to be set from qml so it also inherits `QObject` and uses `Q_PROPERTY` definitions:

```
class MapImageProvider :
        public QObject,
        public QQuickImageProvider
{
        Q_OBJECT

        Q_PROPERTY(QString basePath READ basePath WRITE setBasePath NOTIFY basePathChanged)
    public:
        MapImageProvider();

    signals:
        void basePathChanged();

    public slots:
        QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize) {
QFileInfo imageFile((_basePath + "/baseq3/%1.pk3").arg(id));

    if (imageFile.exists()) {
        QString extractPath((QDir::tempPath() + "/%1.jpg").arg(id));

        //use quazip to read file and return QImage
    }

    return QImage();
    }
    private:
        QString basePath() const;
        void setBasePath(const QString &) noexcept;
        static QString _basePath;
};
```

The problem is that I can't set it from qml plugin's side but only from QQmlEngine's side in another application (which runs qml files):

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImageProvider("map", MapImageProvider);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///ui/views/mainwindow.qml")));

return app.exec();
```

This is very odd because it needs headers of qml plugin in order to set my `MapImageProvider` and more - it will not use the path I need to be specified in order to obtain image from my image provider.

So is there any way exists to register `QQuickImageProvider` right from QML-C++ plugin side like `qmlRegisterType<>()` and others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a [solution](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-imageprovider-imageprovider-cpp.html):

We can do anything with `QQmlEngine` right from the plugin:

```
void initializeEngine(QQmlEngine *engine, const char *uri)
{
    Q_UNUSED(uri);
    engine->addImageProvider("map", new MapImageProvider);
}
```